# Update datatables (JQuery) when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've created a simple form and I'm using the Datatables jQuery plugin to display some data in it. Data are being populated by a php script (process.php) which returns the proper results in JSON format. In the form, there is a button that sends the value of the textbox to the process.php. **The problem is that I cannot update/alter datatable with the new data received by process.php script when the button is clicked**.

The code of the form:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
    <label for="id">Enter an id:</label>  
    <input type="text" name="txtId" id="txtId" value=""/> 
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search"> 
</form>

<div id="results">
    <table class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- data goes here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

To create the datatable, I'm using the following JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                //"bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "process.php"
            } );

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "process.php",  
                data: 'txtId=' + $("txtId").val(),  
                success: function(result) {  
                    oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                    oTable.fnDraw();
                }  
            });
        });
    } );
```

process.php script (works fine) is:

```
<?php
$result="";
if (empty($_REQUEST["txtId"])) {    
    $result = '{"aaData":[["1","Surname1","Name1"]]}';
}
else {
    $result = '{"aaData":[["2","Surname2","Name2"]]}';
}
print $result;
?>
```

Comment: **never** create JSON using string functions. PHP has `json_encode()`. In your case, you'd use  `echo json_encode(array('aaData' => array(array('1', 'Surname1', 'Name1'))));`

Comment: Yes, I know about json_encode() funtion. The above process.php script was written for simplicity reasons. Thanks anyway, ThiefMaster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should also specify `fnServerData` when you setup your datable, if you want to use ajax POST: http://datatables.net/ref#fnServerData

It's also possible that you don't need to call `fnReloadAjax()`, but only `fnDraw()`.  `fnReloadAjax()` is a plugin function, so I assume you did previously load it.

Comment: It seems that I didn't load the fnReloadAjax() plugin. I copied/pasted plugin's code at the beggining of my JQuery script but nothing happend. I'll try again as well as I'll give a try to fnServerData. Thanks Stefan!

Comment: At last, I found the solution! There were 2 problems in my JQuery code. First, I had to add the fnReloadAjax() code after the <script>...</script> tags which loads datatables and before the $(document).ready() statement. Second, I had to alter the JQuery code of my submit button (no need for an AJAX call, only fnReloadAjax() is necessary). Thanks again, Stefan. Nice work!!

Comment: @dimmat:  You are welcome.  So in addition to not needing to call .ajax(), are you saying that you didn't need to specify `fnServerData` either? (In which case GET is used to automatically pass your 'txtId' parameter to your script).  Also, I found mbeasley's answer to be very illuminating and maybe it should be the accepted answer instead.

Comment: Yes, indeed. fnServerData is not necessary!! :-) I also believed that mbeasley's answer will work. But nothing happened with his code... I forgot to mention that I used fnReloadAjax like this: $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){ oTable.fnReloadAjax("process.php?txtId=" + $("txtId").val()); });

Answer (score 4):

`fnReloadAjax` is what you should use (and I believe that it might have a redraw built into the function).  But the problem is that, although you make a second .ajax call, the data in that call is not associated with your datatable at all and will never be bound to it.

Using `fnReloadAjax` will make the same Ajax call that you specified in your table initialization.  So what you need, as Stefan mentioned, is to specify your `fnServerData` parameter in your datatable settings (but trash the `Success` parameters, because something along those lines is already assumed by datatables).  Then just make your button call `fnReloadAjax()`.

Here's what your final code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "sAjaxSource": "process.php",
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json', 
                    "type": "POST", 
                    "url": sSource, 
                    "data": 'txtId=' + $("txtId").val(), 
                    "success": fnCallback
                } );
            }
        } );

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){ 
        oTable.fnReloadAjax();
    });
} );
```

Comment: This is a great explanation.  So it looks as if it might not even be necessary to use `fnServerData` if you don't insist on using POST to pass parameters to the script - since by default GET will be used.

Comment: Your code seems right but it didn't work for me. I solved the problem by adding the fnReloadAjax() plugin API code (found in http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api) after the script tags which load datatables and before $(document).ready() function. I also changed the jquery code of my submit button to this:         
     $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        oTable.fnReloadAjax("process.php?txtId=" + $("txtId").val());
     });                                                             Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! If you use fnReloadAjax specifying a new source for your button click, fnServerData is not needed.  Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

At last, I found the solution! There were 2 problems in my JQuery code:

1. I had to add the fnReloadAjax() code after the script tags which load datatables and before the $(document).ready() statement.
2. I had to alter the JQuery code of my submit button (no need for an AJAX call, only fnReloadAjax() is necessary).

Thank you both Stefan & mbeasley!!

JQuery code now is:

```
//
// fnReloadAjax() code      
//
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
    {
        if ( typeof sNewSource != 'undefined' && sNewSource != null )
        {
            oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
        }
        this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, true );
        var that = this;
        var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
        var aData = [];

        this.oApi._fnServerParams( oSettings, aData );

        oSettings.fnServerData( oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function(json) {
            /* Clear the old information from the table */
            that.oApi._fnClearTable( oSettings );

            /* Got the data - add it to the table */
            var aData =  (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
                that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )( json ) : json;

            for ( var i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ )
            {
                that.oApi._fnAddData( oSettings, aData[i] );
            }

            oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
            that.fnDraw();

            if ( typeof bStandingRedraw != 'undefined' && bStandingRedraw === true )
            {
                oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
                that.fnDraw( false );
            }

            that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );

            /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
            if ( typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback != null )
            {
                fnCallback( oSettings );
            }
        }, oSettings );
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {

        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            //"bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "process.php"
        });

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            oTable.fnReloadAjax("process.php?txtId=" + $("txtId").val());
        });

    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively just destroy the table and recreate it too.

```
var oTable = null;

function reloadTable() {
    if (oTable) {
        oTable.fnDestroy();
    }

    oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        //"bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "process.php"
    } );
}

reloadTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use.

```js
otable.ajax.reload()
```