# Can't use fnReloadAjax datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I tried to reload my datables ajax using `fnReloadAjax()` whenever i click `tambahskpd` button. Here are the syntax:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#tambahskpd').click(function(){
   skpd.fnReloadAjax();
})

      $('#skpdtabel').on('click', 'a.skpdid', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var dataskpd = skpd.row($(this).parents('tr') ).data();
      });

      var skpd = $('#skpdtabel').DataTable({
        "ajax": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pelaporan/show_skpd",    
        "columns": [
           {
              "data": "id",
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                 }
          },
            { "data": "nama_skpd" },
            { "data": "nip" },
            { "data":"nama_pimpinan"},
            { "data":"nama_jabatan"},
            { "data":"id_objek_penugasan"},
            { "data":"id_sub_objek_penugasan"},
            { "data":"alamat"},
            { "data":"id_unit_penugasan"},
          {
           "data": null, 
           "sDefaultContent": '<a href="" class="btn btn-primary skpdid">Pilih</a>'
          }

        ]
    }); 
});
```

Whenever i tried to click `tambahskpd`. It always said `skpd.fnReloadAjax(); is not a function`. What could go wrong with my code ? I used `datatable 1.10`

i have tried this [Update datatables (JQuery) when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160530/update-datatables-jquery-when-button-is-clicked)

I tried **mbeasley** answer, but it didn't work for me

Comment: Please share live demo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fnReloadAjax` is a [**deprecated plugin**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax) you must include if you want to use it. However, since you are using 1.10 you do not need it, the correct syntax is :

```
skpd.ajax.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

To refresh table, try this one:

```
$('#skpdtabel').click(function() {
    var table = $('#skpdtabel').DataTable();
    table.clear().draw();
    $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>pelaporan/show_skpd", {}, function(data) {
        table.rows.add(data).draw();
    }, 'json');
});
```